# How to physically remove data from SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

I need to remove personal data while preserving everything else from a database.

For this I run a set of `update` queries that changes data in all sensitive columns, with some dummy data.

After updates I run shrink database/files.

The issue is that after I open the `.mdf` file and search for the data that was replaced, I'm still able to find it. And I also can find it in a backup file of the database that is made after db shrink.

Question is how to actually remove this data from the database, so that it won't be possible to find it even when looking directly into the database files?

Or alternatively, how to find which object (table, index etc) the page (where I see the data) belongs to if I know the offset (position) in the `.mdf` file?

Comment: If the columns are sensitive [encrypt them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/sql-server-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16) or use [dynamic data masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver16). Backups can be encrypted too. Real security measures are far better than hacky attempts. Deleting a value doesn't delete it from backups you already took. Shrinking will only harm performance, nothing more. And if you want the offset so you can manually tinker with the file, don't.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. A bit of background: I need to provide a backup of production DB to external developer so he will be able to debug and fix issues that is hard to reproduce without real data. But because of the GDPR I need to remove all personal data from it (e.g. names, phone numbers, emails etc.).

Comment: So the values are still in your backup even after removing, huh.  I wonder if it's saving something incremental.  If you right click on your DB properties, is your Recovery Model set to "Full"?  I wonder if changing to "Simple" for the sake of giving the backup to someone else would work.  Because it could remove incremental transaction history.  Just a wild guess.

Answer (score 3):

There can be artifacts of deleted and updated rows in the data pages. These are not visible with T-SQL queries but can be seen in raw data files after the database is restored.

To provide a clean database backup to the third party, I suggest the following:

1. ensure instant file initialization is not enabled
2. create a new empty database with same schema
3. copy the scrubbed data to the new database
4. backup the new cleansed database

Comment: Seems like a lot of extra work... could just use `sp_clean_db_free_space`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two steps. Firstly, rebuild the index on the table you deleted the data from.

```sql
ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.YourTable REBUILD;
```

If the data was stored off-row then you **also** need

```sql
ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.YourTable REORGANIZE WITH (LOB_COMPACTION = ON);
```

Finally, clean out the pages that are not being used.

```sql
EXEC sp_clean_db_free_space;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It has definetely helped to illiminate some issues. Unfortunately I'm still able to find some non dummy data in mdf file but now I think that it could either I missed some tables or could also be some old tables that was already removed? So far, I have found that the page with the data is a Text LOB page that belongs to `sysobjvalues` object even though average length of items is ~30 characters. How to figure out what actual object it belongs to and why `LOB_COMPACTION = ON` didn't helped?

Comment: See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1578/using-dbcc-page-to-examine-sql-server-table-and-index-data/ to find out what is in each page.